# Symlinks in Windows 11 not updating when target is updated

Tags: windows, git-bash, symlink

I have created a symlink to a directory using the Git-bash command `ln -s [target-dir] [alias]`.

I would expect that when I change the contents of [target-dir] that the change is reflected in the symlink, but when I open the symlink it appears to be a static copy of the directory, created at the time I used the command.

How do I get my symlink to act more like a shortcut than a static copy?

I need the symlink as it's needed for compiling CSS. I'm using git-bash and Windows 11. I have ensured Symlinks are enabled when I installed Git-bash.